# Retracting to a bigger compact

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Consider the topological spaces $X$ with the following property:

> For every compact $K\subseteq X$ there is a compact set $L$ such that $K\subseteq L\subseteq X$ and $L$ is a [retract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)#Retract) of $X$.

Let us call this property RBC (Retract to a Bigger Compact). This property seems natural and useful, but I have been unable to find anything directly on it.

It is not hard to see that the following is true:

> **Proposition 1:** Every closed convex topological subspace $C$ of a locally convex metrizable topological vector space $V$ has the RBC property.

*Details on Proposition 1:* Take any nonempty compact $K\subseteq C$. Then, by [known results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)#Absolute_neighborhood_retract_(ANR)) (note, in particular, Ref. [7] there), the closed convex hull $L:=\overline{\text{conv}\,K}$ of $K$ in $V$ is a retract of $V$. Since $L\subseteq C\subseteq V$, it follows that $L$ is a retract of $C$. Since $K$ is compact, $L$ is also compact, and of course $K\subseteq L\subseteq C$. Thus, $C$ has the RBC property. $\Box$

It is also clear that the RBC property is topological and thus invariant with respect to homeomorphisms. Trvially, any compact topological space has the RBC property.

> **Question:** Can one characterize the RBC property?

That is, can one give a usable necessary and sufficient condition for it? Or a usable sufficient condition somewhat close to necessity? By "usable", I mean without the quantifier "there is" in the definition of the RBC property.

I do not know the answer even to this **question:** Is there an example of a topological space without the RBC property?

Thinking about the latter question, I have in mind the "non-retract" example of the $(n-1)$-sphere, which is compact but not a retract of the corresponding closed ball, whereas the ball is compact as well and of course is a retract of itself and of the corresponding $n$-space.

**Update:** The latter question has been answered in comments by erz, Anonymous, and Taras Banakh, who provided examples of topological spaces without the RBC property.

At this point, I would like to make the first question, to characterize the RBC property, more specific:

**Specific question:** Is it true that all Polish spaces have the RBC property?

My **motivation** for all these questions comes from probability. Indeed, any retraction $r$ from $X$ to a compact subset $K$ of $X$ naturally induces the truncation map $\xi\mapsto r\circ\xi$ of random elements $\xi$ of $X$, so that the truncated version $r\circ\xi$ of $\xi$ is a random element of the compact set $K$. Moreover, this truncation map is continuous: if $\xi_t\to\xi$ in distribution, then $r\circ\xi_t\to r\circ\xi$ in distribution.

**Update 2:** Following the latest comment by Anonymous, I have found a recent paper by [Lipham](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.00292), where on the first page one finds an example of a connected completely metrizable space which has no compact connected subset of cardinality greater than one, and therefore does not have the RBC property. By [Mazurkiewicz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set#Properties), this space is also separable and hence Polish. Thus, it is not true that all Polish spaces have the RBC property.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comments, I was thinking of deformation retracts.

Comment: @Wojowu : I did not see your previous comments, but I think for me, with my total inexperience in this field, almost any comments could be useful.

Comment: My comments were saying that the infinite discrete space and the long line do not satisfy your stated property for deformation retracts, though they have pretty obvious retracts onto large compact sets. I'm afraid I don't really see a way to adapt these to the question at hand.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Apologies I've misread the question.

Comment: Concerning your second question: take a strongly rigid space $X$ (i.e. such that if $f:X\to X$ is continuous, then either $f$ is a constant map, or the identity. If $X$ is non-compact, and $f:X\to X$ has a relatively compact image, it must be a constant map. Hence, if you take $K$ to be a two-point set, there is no retraction on a bigger compact set containing $K$. The only remaining part is to find a non-compact strongly rigid space. So far everywhere I looked, the spaces are either compact, or it is not specified (and it is not easy to see) whether they are compact or not.

Comment: As for your first question, ANR's seem to have RBC (not sure if that is valuable)

Comment: For the second question, let X be a connected space such that no compact subset having at least two elements is connected.  Then X obviously fails to have the RBC property.

Comment: @erz : Thank you for your comments, especially the first one, suggesting (to me) that non-RBC spaces are rare (if exist at all).

Comment: @Anonymous : Thank you for your comment. A trivial remark, though: If e.g. $X$ has $\le1$ element, then it obviously has your property: "$X$ is a connected space such that no compact subset having at least two elements is connected". However, then $X$, being compact, also obviously has the RBC property. So, you need your $X$ to be of cardinality $\ge2$. Then, to me, the question becomes this: Is there an example of a space of cardinality $\ge2$ having your property? (I apologize in advance if this question has an obvious answer.)

Comment: Knaster-Kuratowski fan is a connected subset of the plane such that removing a single point makes it totally disconnected. If it has a non-singleton connected compact subset, that subset would be compact, connected and such that removal of a single point makes it totally disconnected. That is impossible, and so, as @Anonymous suggests, the Knaster-Kuratowski fan is not RBC

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that I was considering infinite spaces.  I think that spaces with the property that no compact subset with more than one point is connected are called punctiform spaces.

Comment: @Anonymous The Bernstein subset of the plane is connected but contains no infinite compact subsets, so fails to have RBC.

Comment: Yes, that is one of many known examples.

Comment: Thank you erz, Anonymous, and Taras Banakh for your very helpful comments. I have updated the post accordingly. Also, now I have the specific question: Is it true that all Polish spaces have the RBC property? Plus, I have now provided the motivation.

Comment: I don't have a reference handy, but I think that Mazurkiewicz gave an example of a non-trivial connected, completely metrizable subset of the plane such that no compact subset with more than one point is connected.

Comment: @Anonymous : Thank you very much for your latest comment as well. I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: could you please elaborate on "Using certain known results, it is not hard to see that every closed topological subspace of a locally convex metrizable topological vector space has the RBC property."?

Comment: @erz : Sorry, I missed the convexity condition there. This is now corrected.

Comment: The proof that I thought i had that ANR's have CBR property turned out to be incorrect (i don't know if the claim is correct). Perhaps that could be a natural thing to ask? This class contains manifolds and is stable with respect to taking open subsets. Note that CBR is not stable with respect to taking neither open nor closed subsets.

Comment: @erz : Thank you for your continued interest. ANR certainly seems a more studied property than RBC, so that even a partial reduction of RBC to ANR may be helpful. However, ANR seems to be of the same logical structure as RBC: "$\exists$ a neighborhood ... such that $\exists$ a retraction ..." for ANR versus "$\exists$ a bigger compact than $K$ such that $\exists$ a retraction ..." for RBC. The two remaining $\exists$ quantifiers in the definition of ANR don't by themselves look entirely satisfying, as this leaves the job of finding the existing objects to the user.

Comment: I agree that on principle the definition of ANR is even more complicated than RBC. However, there is so much information about them available, and in particular a lot of "nice" spaces belong to that class.

Comment: I've made a question that specifically asks whether ANR implies CBR https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359384/spaces-that-are-comparable-with-their-compacts